# How can I save the 'role' attributle on my users table on laravel app

Tags: laravel

I have this method for register an user into db, but the role field don't come from a request, because I want assign them to every user that make a registration, so I don't know how save this field in db,
I have this method:
public function action(RegisterRequest $request, User $user)
{

```
    $user = User::create([
        'nome' => $request['nome'],
        'cognome' => $request['cognome'],
        'telefono' => $request['telefono'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    ]);

      $user->assignRole('Regular_user');

    return $user;
}
```

The role is correctly assigned but It don't store in db

Later an user can pass to professional user and I have to find also an update method...
any suggestion?

```
public function assignRole(...$roles)
    {
        $roles = collect($roles)
            ->flatten()
            ->reduce(function ($array, $role) {
                if (empty($role)) {
                    return $array;
                }

                $role = $this->getStoredRole($role);
                if (! $role instanceof Role) {
                    return $array;
                }

                $this->ensureModelSharesGuard($role);

                $array[$role->getKey()] = PermissionRegistrar::$teams && ! is_a($this, Permission::class) ?
                    [PermissionRegistrar::$teamsKey => getPermissionsTeamId()] : [];

                return $array;
            }, []);

        $model = $this->getModel();

        if ($model->exists) {
            $this->roles()->sync($roles, false);
            $model->load('roles');
        } else {
            $class = \get_class($model);

            $class::saved(
                function ($object) use ($roles, $model) {
                    if ($model->getKey() != $object->getKey()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    $model->roles()->sync($roles, false);
                    $model->load('roles');
                }
            );
        }

        if (is_a($this, get_class($this->getPermissionClass()))) {
            $this->forgetCachedPermissions();
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Try `$user->save();` after `$user->assignRole`

Comment: already tryied...return this error:

Comment: general error: 1364 Field 'role' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`nome`, `cognome`, `telefono`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Giovy, Lazza, 33672895095, ggeo@gmail.com, $2y$10$7oZVtafIJvEGuljD8apY0.spzhryUL7rBH3/MrumbBIULNKXpCpgS, 2022-12-21 17:52:33, 2022-12-21 17:52:33))",

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen

Comment: Do you have `role` column defined on users table? Also add snippet of `assignRole` in the question.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen obv ther's a role column in users table I'll add assign role method in description

Comment: what is this `assignRole` function does

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the role to the array like this?
What does your assignRole() method look like?

```
$user = User::create([
'nome' => $request['nome'],
'cognome' => $request['cognome'],
'telefono' => $request['telefono'],
'email' => $request['email'],
'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
'role' => 'Regular_user'
]);
```

Also looks like your error results from the user table not allowing null on the field role, so you can't even create a user with your create statement...

Comment: I can't add role in this way, it return   Field 'role' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`nome`, `cognome`, `telefono`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) v

Comment: You are not using the array i showed you ? Do you have role in $fillables in your User Model ? Add your User Model to the Question and also up method from your create_users_table migration file

Comment: Also your assignRole function seems to have roles not as attribute but as relationship to users model...